# json decode to php variable example needed

Tags: php, mysql, json, decode

Hi I have the following field which is saved as a field called `attachment`.

```
[
   {
    "name":"ClientFiles\/POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement,Rev0_wg1t36oh.pdf",
    "usrName":"POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement,Rev0.pdf",
    "size":172223,
    "type":"application\/pdf",
    "searchStr":"POL02, Impartiality Policy Statement, Rev0.pdf,!:sStrEnd"
   }
]
```

Could someone please tell me how I would write a json_decode code in order to save an element from it as a variable.

for example:

$seachStr = json_decode[attachment->"searchStr"]

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just try using `json_decode()` and dump the output yourself with `print_r()` to see what it looks like? And whatever your example is, it's not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$attachmentArr  = json_decode($attachment,true); // convert the json to php array variable
echo '<pre>', var_dump($attachmentArr), '</pre>';// OUTPUT
$searchStr = $attachmentArr['searchStr'];// Pick the desired element out of the array
echo '<pre>', var_dump($searchStr), '</pre>';// OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thanks, in my example I am getting the field values from following code `$sql = "SELECT * FROM templates_documents WHERE scope = '".$values["msscope"]."'";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql); 
$results = $rs;
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())` so would I use `$attachmentArr = json_decode['$row[attachment]'],true)`